# Android imageview Samsung s4 not stretch

Tags: android, layout, imageview, drawable

I added `logo` in my application. But i saw `little and bad images` in `s4 and tablet devices`. Image in `xxhdpi` folder and res: `577*217`...

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ford"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/animasyon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ford" />
```

[image]

1-nexus one

[image]

2-s4

Comment: I did some research before asking this question. I do not accept negative points.

Comment: Saying things like *"I do not accept negative points"* is just going to get you even more downvotes. I suspect the reason for users downvoting your question is that it isn't at all clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use match_parent to have the image scale on full screen on all devices.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ford"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/animasyon"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ford" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but i found different solution. (Maybe dont good solution).  I write height and width for image . (dp)